# Общие цвета обложки как на YouTube

Tags: php, youtube

Хочу на PHP написать подбор цвета обложки как на YouTube, но как не знаю.
Дело в том, что на YouTube существуют так называемые "музыкальные топик-каналы", в которых загружаются песни, загруженные в Content ID, через YouTube Music, или через Play Music Workstation. У каждого видео загруженного на топик-канале есть своя превью, в которой есть цвет и сама обложка.

Вопрос только, как найти этот цвет? Я пытался найти закономерность в некоторых цветах из значков подобных видео, однако эта самая закономерность не проследилась. Я пытался использовать общий цвет фото, однако ни способ с средним арифметическим RGB всех пикселей, ни способ сжать картинку до 1x1 px, а затем найти цвет этого пикселя, тоже не сработал, ведь результат в корне отличается от оригинала.

Comment: Я не знаю, о чём конкретно тут речь (не разглядывал обложки), но возможно помогут какие-нибудь посты на тему поиска доминирующих цветов: [тык](https://habr.com/ru/post/136530/), [тык](https://habr.com/ru/post/137868/), [тык](https://habr.com/ru/post/156045/)

Comment: Хм, а подгон хороший, скорее всего реально к- средние применяются